# Exposed field in view not showing

Tags: views, search

I'm trying to build me a search function using the exposed fields in a view. But for some reason, the exposed fields don't show up...

My main search module is enabled, my D7-website is indexed and I have a module called `Better Exposed Filters` enabled. But still, no exposed fields are popping up. What do I do wrong not to get any exposed fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it myself. The trick was to turn on AJAX (for some weird reason).